# Null exception when trying to use a list

Tags: c#

I have StartingMap that inherits from Map. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Map m_map;
List<Map> m_versions;

m_versions.add(new StartingMap(...)); // create null reference exeption

m_map= new StartingMap(...); // no error and load the map perfectly
```

Why do I get an error with the first one and not the second one ? I am doing the same thing.

Comment: you have to create an instance fo the List<Map> m_versions before calling a method on it (m_versions = new List<Map>()).

Answer (score 6):

You must instantiate `m_versions`, like

```
m_versions = new List<Map>();
```

Comment: Guys, english help here: is *instantiate* the proper word?

Comment: Yes; that is the correct word.

Comment: Yes it is. Google very usefully includes definitions now, I've noticed. =D http://www.google.com/search?q=instantiate

Comment: @andre: Yes.  *Instantiate* means *to create an instance of*.  Initialize is not really situationally correct: it implies that you already have the object, but that it is not ready.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. That's the word we use in pt-BR also, just wanted to be sure that it had the same meaning for you.

Comment: You're not instantiating `m_versions`, you're assigning to it. You're instantiating a new `List<Map>`. (You're not even initializing `m_versions`, as it's already initialized to null.)

Comment: @Rawling But `m_versions` has the instance reference. This is a pointless discussion, right?

Comment: @Andre You did ask for language advice! "Instantiate" has a very specific meaning in programming - to create an instance of an object. This is separate from storing an instance of an object in a variable.

Comment: @Rawling Oh yes, now I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate List before you add any items to the collection. In the second example you are just calling the constructor of StartingMap completely different things.

So before you can add any items to your list you need to:

```
m_versions = new List<Map>()
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize the m_versions:

```
m_versions = new List<Map>();
```

before you can use it and add items to it.